# Create TCP TUNNELING system using Indy

Tags: delphi, tcp, proxy, indy

Hi is it possible to create intermediary application which will act as tcp proxy server? It would be made of two components. IdTCPServer and IdTCPClient. The idea is:

Application > connects to IdTCPServer > all data is redirected to > IdTCPClient which is connected to the destination.

And the data received by TCPClient will be redirected to the IdTCPServer and Application. 
I made such simple app, and it works in HTTP requests, but it fails when I tried to use it for RDP Client ( I got error that Protocol is wrong). Is it even possible? I use ReadByte method, and each single byte is sent to the other IOHandler.

I would like to create some sort of virtual tcp channel which would allow connections over NAT.

I wasn't clear enough. What I want to achieve is something like this:

RDP Server < IdTCPClient <> IdTCPclient > NAT > IdTCPServer  < RDPClient.

Answer (score 4):

> Application > connects to IdTCPServer > all data is redirected to > IdTCPClient which is connected to the destination.
>
> And the data received by TCPClient will be redirected to the IdTCPServer and Application.

In fact, Indy has a component specifically for that very purpose - `TIdMappedPortTCP`.

Set its `MappedHost` and `MappedPort` properties to point at the intended destination, then activate it, and all inbound connections will automatically be directed to the destination, and data passed back and forth in both directions.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to add just a comment, but don't have enough points for that.
Your request says you want to "redirect", for which Remy supplied the answer.

However, your description sounds like you want to pass the data yourself (man-in-the-middle).  [RDP contains some guards against that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol#Security_issues), though earlier versions may have been more open to it.

You may want to specify the question more tightly if actual redirect is not what you are looking for.

Comment: yes, I wasn't precise enough. I edited the question.